# How to fully connect component pad with the ground plane

Tags: pcb, ground, eaglecad, ground-plane

I'm trying to make a simple PCB board on eagle.

I've learned how to make a ground plane, and it worked great. But I wonder, why is the component pins/pads connected to ground as more like a plus (**+**) sign, not all side. Is this normal?

Can I make it so that every side of the pins connect to the ground plane?
Or is it just not how it works?

Comment: It’s called thermal relief. Depending on your solder method you can change this behavior in your settings.

Comment: A bit more on what winny said.  That's related to being able to easily solder to the pad.  If the spokes weren't there, you would have to heat up the pad and all the surrounding ground plane copper in order for the solder to "stick".  The thermal reliefs allow the use of a smaller soldering iron & tip in the case of manual soldering.

Comment: When prototyping, thermal reliefs are a good idea even if it's not being manually soldered, because it will make it easier to make manual modifications to the circuit later. In a production design, my understanding is that thermal reliefs are generally not used except for parts that can't be reflow-soldered, though, as the reflow process heats the entire board anyway so there'd be no advantage to them.